# Is there a textual promise of eternal life in the Quran?

Tags: quran, jannah, akhirah

Perhaps the most famous Biblical quote is from John 3:16

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

This is basically a one line summary of Christianity: believe in Jesus and you will have eternal life.

Is there are similar textual promise of paradise in the Quran?

Answer (score 5):

The idea that those who believe and do good deeds are promised eternal paradise is repeated throughout the Qu'ran. There are probably too many examples to list here, but one that I think best captures what you're looking for can be found in Surah Luqman:

> Indeed, those who believe and do righteous deeds - for them are the Gardens of Pleasure.
>
> Wherein they abide eternally; [it is] the promise of Allah [which is] truth. And He is the Exalted in Might, the Wise.
>
> <sup>[[Luqman 8-9](http://legacy.quran.com/31/8-9)]</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Quran promises of Reward to believers, and punishment to disbelievers.

### Precision in description

The arabic words mentioned in Quran about entering Paradise or Hellfire are:

**Khalid** (adjective): to remain/stay for a long period of time.

**Abad** (adverb): Eternally, without an end.

Now if you study the way those two words were used to describe the stay in Paradise or Hellfire please consider the following two examples:

Sura Nisa[4-57]

> But those who believe and do righteous deeds - We will admit
>   them to gardens beneath which rivers flow, **wherein they abide forever**.
>   For them therein are purified spouses, and We will admit them to
>   deepening shade.

while in the same Sura(chapter) [4-13]

> These are the limits [set by] Allah, and whoever obeys Allah and His
>   Messenger will be admitted by Him to gardens [in Paradise] under which
>   rivers flow, **abiding eternally** therein; and that is the great
>   attainment.

### Times Mentioned

A beautiful observation, of the number of times the word eternally forever mentioned reveals mercy of the Al-mighty

when related to Paradise **8 times**. 
when related to hellfire **3 times**.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 3):

There are many such verses in the Quran:

> إِنَّ الْمُتَّقِينَ فِي مَقَامٍ أَمِينٍ    ... **لَا يَذُوقُونَ فِيهَا الْمَوْتَ** إِلَّا الْمَوْتَةَ الْأُولَىٰ ۖ وَوَقَاهُمْ عَذَابَ الْجَحِيمِ
>
> Indeed, the righteous will be in a secure place; ... **They will not taste death therein** except the first death, and He will have protected them from the punishment of Hellfire.
>
> <sup>— Quran  [44:51](https://quran.com/44/51) ... [44:56](https://quran.com/44/56)</sup>
>
> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ لَهُمْ **أَجْرٌ غَيْرُ مَمْنُونٍ**
>
> Indeed, those who believe and do righteous deeds - for them is a **reward uninterrupted.**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 41:8](https://quran.com/41/8)</sup>
>
> لَا يَمَسُّهُمْ فِيهَا نَصَبٌ **وَمَا هُم مِّنْهَا بِمُخْرَجِينَ**
>
> No fatigue will touch them therein, **nor from it will they be removed**.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 15:48](https://quran.com/15/48)</sup>
>
> وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ سَنُدْخِلُهُمْ جَنَّاتٍ تَجْرِي مِن تَحْتِهَا الْأَنْهَارُ **خَالِدِينَ فِيهَا أَبَدًا ۖ وَعْدَ اللَّهِ حَقًّا** ۚ وَمَنْ أَصْدَقُ مِنَ اللَّهِ قِيلًا
>
> But the ones who believe and do righteous deeds - We will admit them to gardens beneath which rivers flow, **wherein they will abide forever. [It is] the promise of Allah, [which is] truth**, and who is more truthful than Allah in statement.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:122](https://quran.com/4/122)</sup>